# Does TensorFlow optimize to avoid unnecessary re-execution of graphs?

Tags: tensorflow

I understand *roughly* how a TensorFlow graph is evaluated when one of the `Tensors` it contains is evaluated: the execution of `run` or `eval` for that tensor will trigger all of the cascading computations in the graph needed compute the value of that tensor and, as a result, any tensors that "lead to it" in the graph will also have been computed, and any operations connecting them will have been run.

As a consequence, if I have a graph containing the tensor `out_a` the computation of which involves (perhaps among many other things) operations that use `int_b` which in turn (eventually) requires execution of the operation `an_op` which itself (eventually) uses `in`, executing

```
a, b, o = sess.run([out_a, int_b, an_op], feed_dict={in: x})
```

will evaluate `out_a`, `int_b` and `an_op` *just once*: the computation of `out_a` and `int_b` both use the same execution of `an_op`; and the computation used to supply `int_b` is the same one used in computing `out_a`. (And if I later reference `a`, for example, I'm using the value of the evaluated tensor `out_a`, so no further execution occurs as a result.)

But what happens if I don't combine my operations in this way:

```
o = sess.run(an_op, feed_dict={in: x})
# ... and later yet, after I remember I need `int_b`:
b = sess.run(int_b, feed_dict={in: x})
# ... later, after I remember I need `out_a`:
a = sess.run(out_a, feed_dict={in: x})
```

Is there any optimization that TensorFlow performs in this case to avoid computing `an_op` a second and third time, and `int_b` a second time, possibly triggering side effects of those computations?

Comment: based on my observations, you have to put all those variables in single run to use same execution (like case 1). If you do like second case, second and third run will again execute the common ops and give you next result.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any optimization that TensorFlow performs in this case to
>   avoid computing an_op a second and third time, and int_b a second
>   time, possibly triggering side effects of those computations?

No, it is up to a developer to remember what computations will need to be executed and put all of them in the list in your [sess.run](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Session#run) function (the way you described).

You can verify it by running the following code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime

n = 3000
t = np.random.rand(n,n)
a = tf.Variable(t)
b = tf.matmul(a, a)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    startTime = datetime.now()
    _ = sess.run(b)
    print datetime.now() - startTime

    startTime = datetime.now()
    _ = sess.run(b)
    print datetime.now() - startTime

    startTime = datetime.now()
    _ = sess.run(b)
    print datetime.now() - startTime
```

which on my machine returns:

```
0:00:02.798704
0:00:02.940005
0:00:03.039798
```

If the data would be cached, the second run would return in no time.

Comment: that test should not be expected to detect whether tensorflow is caching results between session.run invocations, because you're using a random input, which a reasonable caching implementation would mark as uncacheable.

Comment: @lahwran thank you very much for spotting this. Fixed the problem.